Which diode releases the most heat when used as a low voltage heating source?
I was reviewing Grace Gius &al.: Hot diodes!: Dirt cheap cooking and electricity for the global poor?. By using a series of diodes the system gets to be more efficient than using resistance wire for heating. Theoretically, it would be a medium cost installation used in conjunction with solar power a sand
thermal battery and a thermocouple which would result in free heat.

What article is this from? Resistive heaters are by definition 100% efficient. The only way to "exceed" that would be to use a heat pump like a Peltier.

There's no free heat, or free other energy. All loads heat up. If you push some equal amount of power into a diode or resistor, they dissipate the power into heat equally with 100% efficiency.

...100% efficient up to the point they start to emit non-heat radiation, such as visible light

@EugeneSh., but in a closed container, that light changes back to heat. Of course, any black body above the surrounding energy would emit some radiation. ;-)

you could store heat from solar collectors directly ... no electrical middleman required

If that's what it said, then the article is definitely not "scientific".

Citation needed please.

in a sand battery which takes days to cool this could be an answer
to when the power is off. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352728519300508

(Beware LEDs: they are less efficient in turning electricity to heat.) Give Lawrence Monroe and the authors the benefit of doubt: a load of diodes can stay closer to a solar panel's MPP than a resistive one. (There used to be "solar cooking" with a black pot and concave mirror.)

Please see How to reference material written by others

The answer to your question is: the diodes whose composed characteristics passes closest to the maximum power transfer points of your solar panel for different values of illumination.
A resistor has a linear characteristic V = R I, where R is constant. You can have a fixed R operate near MPP (Maximum Power Point) for a given level of illumination, but not for all others. You work in an inefficient way when you are far from noon, or when the sky is partially clouded.
A diode is a nonlinear resistor whose characteristic I = I(V) is exponential. N diodes in series gives an exponential characteristic that is flat under a certain value of voltage and then rises steeply. This nonlinear load curve can cross the various panel characteristics at different lighting levels in points that are very close to the respective MPPs. This results in a more efficient use of the energy provided by the panel in different conditions.
See for example: "Hot Diodes!: Dirt cheap cooking and electricity for the global poor?" here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352728519300508?via%3Dihub
Have a look at figure 7.
PS
I really hope that by reviewing you don't mean 'peer reviewing'.

not peer review just don't like my ignorance in the subject.

P=I*V, end of story. Doesn't change if I=I(V) or I=G*V.

Welcome to the site, Fred, but that answer is unlikely to give the OP any insights. I have many decades of electrical engineering in industry but I don't know what I = I(V) or I = GV means and you haven't explained it. They may be specific to your region. Can you expand it and improve it?

(@Transistor I = I(V): current is a function of/depends on voltage.)

I = f(V) would be a better way to say that.


Although your link with block diagrams could have merit with an illustration of a fixed voltage to regulate the voltage from a PV,and this could be a level 1 grade MPPT tracking concept at 82% of Voc, it does not have to be power diodes and could be "any linear voltage regulator" acting as a power zener in a string of serial linear regulators, the usefulness of any concept must bear the burden of detailed design specs with reliable requirements.  The loads must occur together otherwise energy is lost in a serial chain.

Where are the design specs for energy conversion? and losses?

I meant the storage battery charge/discharge specs. IDK of any practical sand batteries.

After reading the article, I realized the Engineer did not know about MTBF and Arrhenius Equations. His conclusions are even worse. He is running the diodes beyond the Absolute maximum of 150 'C and recommends too few rather than too many 4 cent 5 A diodes to operate at 160 'C rather than improving the thermodynamics. with a drop to 90 'C for water which is dangerous for personal use of water taps and would require safety insulated pipes.

Repairability is poor with glued diodes and, scrap is more likely  with failure in 1~2 yrs. Cost is > $5 in qty=20 but cost of pot labor is much higher.
